# Mapping TPT inheritance in Entity Framework 6 (core)

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Consider two tables, table BaseService with PK ID, and table SubService with PK BaseServiceID, which is a foreign key to ID in the BaseService table. I wish to map these to classes in EF6 where SubService inherits from BaseService. I'm not sure how to describe in the mapping that the foreign key is from SubService.BaseServiceID to BaseService.ID. At the moment I have something like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<SubService>(e => {
        e.ToTable("SubService");
    });
```

and

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<BaseService>(e => {
        e.ToTable("BaseService");
    e.HasKey(x =>  x.ID);
});
```

When I query though, the resulting query tries to join using BaseService.ID to SubService.ID. I've tried a few variations on my mapping, but I'm getting nowhere - can anyone suggest how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing, EF doesn't currently support having different column names for the keys in the tables in a TPT mapping.  If you configure one entity to map its "Id" property to a column called "FooId", then all entities in the hierarchy will map their keys to "FooId".

You can create an [EF Core Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues) to provide feedback on this scenario.

Comment: No need to create new one - [Allow specifying different key facets per table in TPT, TPC or entity splitting #27972](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27972). And wait couple years :-)

Comment: Thanks, that fits with what I’ve found - there’s no api to specify the mapping. Time to investigate a workaround ☹️

Comment: Those would be 1) Map your entities to views or 2) Use associations instead of inheritance in your entity model.

Comment: Yes, I've mapped to views for now, and will revisit once we've retired the previous version of the software

Answer (score -1):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SubService>()
        .ToTable("SubService")
        .HasRequired(s => s.BaseService)
        .WithMany(b => b.SubServices)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.BaseServiceID);
```

*In this example, a HasRequired method is used to specify that the entity requires a and the method is used to specify the ability to navigate on the side of the relationship. Finally, `BaseService' property class'SubService' 'BaseService' 'WithMany' 'BaseService' 'HasForeign' 'KeyBase' 'ServiceID' 'SubService'*

Comment: HasRequired doesn't seem to be a valid method - which version of EF are you using? I'm using EF Core 6

Comment: That also sounds more like setting up an association rather than an inheritance relationship. A child class shouldn't have a navigation property to its base classs?